# How do I get the showing rows from datatable Scroller extention?

Tags: javascript, events, datatable, callback, datatables

When using the [Scroller](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) extention for datatables, you don't have pagination but all rows in one scrollbar. I would like to know, what event is fired after scrolling down the tables, to e.g. see row 50-60 of 100.. I also need to know how to get that 10 rows out from the datatable. I'am using the lastest versions. Thanks alot.

This is how you get the rows from the current page in Datatable.net *without* the [Scroller](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) extention.

```
drawCallback: function (settings) {
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

    // Output the data for the visible rows to the browser's console
    console.log(api.rows({ page: 'current' }).data().length);
}
```

> **Update 1**: My Init of Scroller table:

```
initScrollerTable = function ($table, url, inclFilter, dataTableOptionsSpecific) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataParameterHelper.getCommonData(),
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function (rows) {
        var dataTableOptions = $.extend(
            {},
            { data: rows },
            dataTableOptionsSpecific
        );

        initTable($table, inclFilter, dataTableOptions);
    });
};
```

> **Update 2** Deeper elaborating on the origional reason for the question to clarify.

Okay long story short. My table contained 26000 rows, and it took 7mins for me to load it. It contained of ALOT of DB calls and the JSON was a size of 21MB! I wanted to optimize it.
First attempt: I tripped my json to absolute minimum bringing it down to 1.5MB but it still took almost `7mins`. On the second test it contained all the html, with hardcoded numbers/strings and i did 0 DB calls. It only took `3.5secs!`. Yesterday I didn't knew I only had to focus on optimizing my calls to the DB.
Yesterday, when I posted the origional questing, my idea was to populate the table without any data pulled form the DB, and instead load them in a kind of lazy loading way. Let's say I showed the 10 first rows. with 3 column each where I need to call the DB for each cell, that's 30 times total. So the idea was to make 30 request for the (10) current rows, and replace the placeholder with the actually value. If you understand. I would still be better than 26.000 * 3 DB calls :)
And for that I needed to hook up on an event to get the 10 current rows-id's, I could then loop through making the 30 AJAX request. So maybe it's the scroller event I need for that, if there is someone like that. 
But I don't know if it's a good idea. Usually a "good" idea is only "good" before/until you learn the best pratice :)
I think I will start focusing on reducing the DB calls with some inner joins and what have you, retrieving a big resultset I can loop through and populate all my 26.000(and later 50.000) rows, in under 15 secs!

Comment: I think you need to look into [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/data#Server-side-processing) with that many records. From what I understand you wanted to catch scrolling event to load data from the server, but DataTables does it for you with `serverSide: true` parameter. However in server-side processing mode you need to perform filtering, ordering and pagination on the server yourself. There is a sample `ssp.class.php` that comes in DataTables distribution that helps if your server-side language is PHP.

Comment: I have used the server-side for a couple of months now. I just replaced all of them and my client-side with the Scroller (client-side 50.000) extensions the last month. The thing I don't like with server-side, is self performing the filtering server-side. It can never be as good as the filtering on the client cached table.

Comment: I disagree, properly indexed tables performs great in server-side processing mode, it has been working fine with +3M records for me.

Comment: Sounds good, but how did you solve a scenario like this where let's say you have 3 columns (name, email, age, country). If you write "us joe 30" in the filter. Then you have 3 filter words to search with and 4 tables to look in(let's pretend name, email and age is in each of their db-table to keep it simple). That's a total of 12 db searches, isn't that a problem? We can open a chat or use skype if you like. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`xhr`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event to handle Ajax requests and [`page.info()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info%28%29) to retrieve information about the table as shown below.

Please note that event handler needs to be attached before you initialize your table to handle initial Ajax request.

```
$('#example').on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
    var info = api.page.info();

    console.log('Data has been loaded', info);
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4np7od2z/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: The event `xhr.dt` isn't fired for me. See my Update 1. Could it be because I retrieve all the rows first. I does this to have a very quick filter with the cached table, but I don't know how smart it is, as for now getting 20.000 rows takes 4mins for me :(
I can see you get the 10 rows with the ajax callback.

Comment: I can see in your fine fiddle, that info contains what I was looking for, and it's using the Api you thought me, so I will accept because it's the solution. 

The xhr.dt event isn't fired for me though and I still don't know why but maybe I will figure it out later. (I have attached it before initialization).

Comment: @radbyx, thanks for catching the missing semicolon :). You're not getting `xhr.dt` event because you're retrieving all the data initially and supplying it directly to the DataTables. Can you please clarify in your question what event you want to catch again? Would attaching event handler to `scroll` event and retrieving `page.info()` solve your problem?

Comment: More context added, sorry for not being clear the first time :)

Comment: The thing is, that we love the filter function. It finds everything in the cached table in no time, and we build our features on it. 
As I understand, for that to work, there is no other way than to give the datatable all of it's data for the filter to work, on each string in the table that you can see.
And earlier version we had, our filter made a request to our server, making DB calls and returning the "10" rows. It can be fast, but the big disadvange is, that you can't easially searh in all your DB tables to find the correct rows (also the row value can be composed making it impossible)

Comment: @radbyx, let's continue our discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89418/discussion-between-gyrocode-com-and-radbyx).